# Contrast if regression coefficients of two predictors are equals

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, contrasts, diagnostic

I've got this model:

```
model <- lm(biomass ~ salin+ph+k+na+zn, data = sparData)
```

with sparData dataset:

```
   obs loc tip.veg biomass salin   ph       k      na      zn
1    1  OI    DVEG     676    33 5.00 1441.67 35184.5 16.4524
2    2  OI    DVEG     516    35 4.75 1299.19 28170.4 13.9852
3    3  OI    DVEG    1052    32 4.20 1154.27 26455.0 15.3276
4    4  OI    DVEG     868    30 4.40 1045.15 25072.9 17.3128
5    5  OI    DVEG    1008    33 5.55  521.62 31664.2 22.3312
16  16  SI    DVEG     396    30 3.25  646.65 17307.4 31.2865
17  17  SI    DVEG     352    27 3.35  514.03 12822.0 30.1652
18  18  SI    DVEG     328    29 3.20  350.73  8582.6 28.5901
19  19  SI    DVEG     392    34 3.35  496.29 12369.5 19.8795
20  20  SI    DVEG     236    36 3.30  580.92 14731.9 18.5056
31  31  SM    DVEG     824    26 4.85  936.26 20436.0 18.9875
32  32  SM    DVEG    1196    29 4.60  894.79 12519.9 20.9687
33  33  SM    DVEG    1960    25 5.20  941.36 18979.0 23.9841
34  34  SM    DVEG    2080    26 4.75 1038.79 22986.1 19.9727
35  35  SM    DVEG    1764    26 5.20  898.05 11704.5 21.3864
```

How can I contrast if regression coefficients of k and zn are equals? I'm a little lost in this.

Coeff. are:

```
Call:
lm(formula = biomass ~ salin + ph + k + na + zn, data = spartData)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-707.55 -177.46   30.92  144.08  643.21 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 2473.99632 3030.81508   0.816   0.4354  
salin        -87.22784   53.34201  -1.635   0.1364  
ph           415.44896  220.27220   1.886   0.0919 .
k              0.02802    0.64766   0.043   0.9664  
na            -0.01272    0.02475  -0.514   0.6197  
zn           -24.00394   40.06079  -0.599   0.5638  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 387.9 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.738, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5925 
F-statistic: 5.071 on 5 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.01739
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I contrast" ? Do you mean "how can I test" ?

Comment: Yes, make an hypothesis testing. Check if they are equals. :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach for testing linear hypothesis, like the one you are dealing with, is to compare the full or unrestricted model with the restricted model though the log-likelihood ratio test. In your case the full model is the one you fitted, whereas the restricted model, i.e., the one under $H_0$, is

$biomass = \beta_0 + \beta_1*salin+\beta_2*ph+\beta_3*k+\beta_4*na+\beta_3*zn+\epsilon\\
         \qquad\quad= \beta_0 + \beta_1*salin+\beta_2*ph+\beta_3*(k+zn)+\beta_4*na+\epsilon$

Notice that here the estimated $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_4)$ can be different from the corresponding estimates from the full model, but you don't care about them. What you care is how much lower is the log-likelihood of the restricted model when compared to the full model. For this you need to compare their log-likelihoods through a log-likelihood ratio test.

In R you can do it like this

```
 # let's load the data, I've copy-pasted your dataset in a text file
> sparData <- read.table("sparData.txt",
                         header = TRUE,row.names = "obs")

 # fit the unrestricted model
> mod.spar <- lm(biomass ~ salin+ph+k+na+zn, data = sparData)
> summary(mod.spar)

Call:
lm(formula = biomass ~ salin + ph + k + na + zn, data = sparData)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-707.55 -177.46   30.92  144.08  643.21 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 2473.99632 3030.81508   0.816   0.4354  
salin        -87.22784   53.34201  -1.635   0.1364  
ph           415.44896  220.27220   1.886   0.0919 .
k              0.02802    0.64766   0.043   0.9664  
na            -0.01272    0.02475  -0.514   0.6197  
zn           -24.00394   40.06079  -0.599   0.5638  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 387.9 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.738, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5925 
F-statistic: 5.071 on 5 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.01739


  # fit the restricted model under H0: k = zn
> mod.spar.res <- lm(biomass ~ salin+ph+I(k+zn)+na, data = sparData)

  # log-likelihood ratio test for the restricted vs unrestricted
> anova(mod.spar.res, mod.spar)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: biomass ~ salin + ph + I(k + zn) + na
Model 2: biomass ~ salin + ph + k + na + zn
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     10 1409289                           
2      9 1353912  1     55377 0.3681  0.559

 # which is equivalent to:
> library(car)
> linearHypothesis(mod.spar, "k = zn")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
k - zn = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: biomass ~ salin + ph + k + na + zn

  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     10 1409289                           
2      9 1353912  1     55377 0.3681  0.559
```

As you can see from the p-value, you cannot reject your $H_0$.

Comment: Thank you!  I will explore this functionality till ur next fully detailed answer. By the way I've edited mi question to include the full dataset ;)

Comment: I've edited the answer, giving few more details. Hope it helps.